# GeoJSON Marker from URL and setFilter() then no more custom popup

Tags: mapbox

I try to load geoJson and then apply filter on those pois. Each marker has a custom popup.
Binding custom popup on each marker works fine until i call the setFilter() on my featureLayer.
Basically my code looks like this

```
var map;
var featureLayer;

     function initMap(mapInfos){

            var southWest = L.latLng(mapInfos.sw.lat, mapInfos.sw.lng),
                northEast = L.latLng(mapInfos.ne.lat, mapInfos.ne.lng),
                bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

            map = L.mapbox
                    .map('map', 'oxyde.xxxxxx', {'maxBounds' : bounds})
                    .setView([mapInfos.center.lat, mapInfos.center.lng], mapInfos.defaultZoom);
            featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().loadURL('/pois').addTo(map);
            featureLayer.on('ready', setContentToAllPois);
            return mapInfos;
    }

    function setContentToAllPois(){
        var promises = new Array();
        featureLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
                promises.push(setContentToPoi(layer));
        });
        $.when.apply($.when.apply, promises)
            .done(doneLoadingPois)
            .fail(logError);
    }

    function setContentToPoi(layer){
        var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred(),
        poi = layer.feature.properties.poi;

        $.get('/poi/' + poi._id + '/content')
            .done(function(content){
                layer.bindPopup(content);
                dfd.resolve(layer);
            })
            .fail(function(e){
                dfd.reject(e);
            });
        return dfd.promise();


function doneLoadingPois(){

        featureLayer.setFilter(function(feature) {
            return true;
        })

    }
```

If I comment the setFilter(...) line in doneLoadingPois the popups show fine. 
 1- What am i missing here ?
 2- Why do i have to use a featureLayer var ? (using map.featureLayer doesn t work, it seems it s not the same object)

thank you !

Answer (score 2):

`.setFilter()` resets the contents of the layer, so this is expected behavior - calling it replaces the contents of the layer, including any custom popups. If you want to bind popups whenever layers are added to the map, you can use the `.on('layeradd'` event.

Comment: its not clear for me on which object do i have to use the .on('layeradd') event ?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I have the EXACT same problem.

Comment: sorry, i dont work on this project anymore. I dont remember which workaround i used...